# Laravel 9 Livewire The photo failed to upload

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-livewire

I started learning Laravel 9 livewire. I am trying to make an image upload application. I did the exact example in the Livewire documentation, but I get an error that the image could not be uploaded. When I do the same application on my mac computer, it works without any problems. It doesn't work when I do it on my windows computer.

ImageUpload.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class ImegaUpload extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $photo;

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'photo' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max
        ]);

        $this->photo->store('photos');
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.imega-upload');
    }
}
```

image-upload.blade.php

```
<div>
    <h1>Image upload</h1>
    <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
        <input type="file" wire:model="photo">

        @error('photo')
            <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror

        <button type="submit">Save Photo</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Error
[image]

I'm doing the example in the Livewire documentation but still getting the error. Not even the livewire-temp folder is created.

Comment: Looks like a permission problem... is the folder writable? What does your logfile say?

Comment: prints this error in log file when I try to upload image

Comment: local.ERROR: Path cannot be empty {"exception":"[object] (ValueError(code: 0): Path cannot be empty at C:\\laragon\\www\\example-app\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\FilesystemAdapter.php:397)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like your PHP.ini is missing

> sys_temp_dir

and

> upload_tmp_dir

uncomment and then set its value.

mine example.

Laragon on win 10:

> sys_temp_dir = "c\laragon\tmp"

> upload_tmp_dir = "c\laragon\tmp"

all temp files will go to that location (not just uploaded)

Answer (score 1):

In 
`App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies` 
change
`protected $proxies;`
to 
`protected $proxies = '*';`
it helped me